# Is it normal to see the heavy load message before most workflows start?

Tags: workflow

Is it normal for this message *Due to heavy load, the latest workflow operation has been queued. It will attempt to resume at a later time* to occur before most workflows starts?

Comment: Do you get this under load or are you the only person on the box?

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if it's a workflow that executes on a large number of items, yes you could see the queueing message.  There can only be 50 active instances of the same workflow executing at the same time I believe.  So if the workflow is on a large list or library with lots of additions or edits triggering the workflow, you may run into this frequently.

Answer (score 0):

are you starting the workflow from the user account administrator ?

I've seen this message in this particular case.